# How to completely remove Thunderbird?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird

Since I prefer to use Evolution, I would really like to completely remove Thunderbird from my PC. I already performed `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*` but `locate thunderbird` still lists some hits:

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/thunderbird:thunderbird.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/thunderbird.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
```

How can I completely remove it?

Comment: did you `sudo updatedb` to update the locate data base?

Comment: Thanks! Well after updatedb is better... but still few hits. Looks more like two icons and thunderbird:thunderbird.desktop

Comment: No big deal then

Comment: What are the full paths of those hits?

Comment: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/thunderbird:thunderbird.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/thunderbird.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg

Answer (score 89):

This will **completely** remove thunderbird from your system.

`sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*`

Here is what went wrong in your case.

- You will need to wait for the locate database to update, or force update by `sudo updatedb` before the system picks the changes. Or use `locate -e` to print only files existing at the time `locate` is run.
- The files you see in `/usr/share/app-install` belong to Ubuntu Software Center.
- The files in `/usr/share/icons` belong to the corresponding icon theme.

Comment: `sudo apt purge thunderbird` seemed to remove all for me - `thunderbird* thunderbird-gnome-support* thunderbird-locale-en* thunderbird-locale-en-us*`

Answer (score 3):

A complete purge includes

1. `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*`
2. `rm -r /home/<username>/.thunderbird`

then you can reinstall it from zero, otherwise, all the information in `.thunderbird` will still exist.

Comment: You can use `rm -r ~/.thunderbird` instead `rm -r /home/<username>/.thunderbird`