# Weird Thunderbird Uninstall Problem

Tags: uninstall, thunderbird

Ok.  I know there are other posts about uninstalling Thunderbird, but my problem is weird.
First when try and find Thunderbird in the Software Center to uninstall it it does not show up as installed, but only in the list of available to install.  YET I do have it and MANY other Thunderbird files and folders when I do a search in the File System:

[image]

Ok, so I did the old "sudo apt-get remove --purge thunderbird -y"  and I got this back:

[image]

It looks to me that it DIDN'T remove Thunderbird etc. and when I searched "File System"  I got the same result as above!

My question is, why is this weirdness happening, and can I manually grab all of those "Thunderbird" Files and Folders and manually trash them safely?
Are there any "Thunderbird" files that might cause problems in any way if I trash them?

Ok, I tried using gksu nautilus and got an error message:

[image]

What does this mean?  Be kind, I'm a novice!

Ok, I tried gksu nautilus again and got this warning:

[image: gksu nautilus warning]

Comment: Nothing to worry , http://askubuntu.com/questions/250996/how-to-completely-remove-thunderbird

Comment: If your question is resolved, please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can safely delete the folders. However, folders with a lock on them can't be deleted by moving to trash.

Fire up a terminal, and enter the following to become root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then repeat your search and delete the thunderbird files.

**UPDATE**

Prior to 13.04 , try `gksu` instead of `sudo`.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB on a HP Pavillion Laptop.  Should I then use gksu ?  I've used sudo for other things with no problems.

Comment: Use gksu to be on the safe side. If it works, mark the answer correct.

Comment: Ok, I'm a frightened noobie to Linux so when I get a message like this after typing in a command in the terminal I get a bit freaked:

Comment: just relax and only delete thunderbird files, youll be fine

Comment: Ok, but answer my update to my question first.  
What does it mean about the folder (see above) and
what is the command?  gksu nautilus ? If so I get that 
message above.  Should I use sudo afterall?

Comment: Use gksu, that message is just there to scare off people who haven't a clue of what they're doing. Only delete thunderbird files, and nothing else.

Comment: Ok this is what is happening:
I run gksu nautilus and I get a home window showing only the desktop folder.  I did a search in THAT WINDOW for "Thunderbird" and it brought up all those thunderbird files I've been longing to delete.  When I try to shift+delete: Nothing happens.  They won't delete and I get no message about it.  
After a while I got that same warning message above.
What step am I missing?  Am I supposed to create a folder?

Comment: First just shift select, then just delete.

Comment: Ok still nothing.  I looked around and found that while in root anything I am to do should be done in the terminal?  
Or am I supposed to use the "home" window that pops up?  
If the later then it still does nothing.  I still seem locked out.  
Can anyone hold my hand and walk be through this?

Comment: Why don't you try deleting them one-by-one...

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with CTRL+ALT+T then type as  `sudo updatedb` . that will do the job .

see [How to completely remove Thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250996/how-to-completely-remove-thunderbird) fore more Information.