# Thunderbird 45.5.1 - not pulling specific inbox's new messages

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

By parsing through miles of pages on AskUbuntu I see that many have been dealing with similar issue, maybe even same, over the years. Most of similar issues have been resolved, but my is still present and nothing I found to address similar didn't help me addresses this issue.

VERSIONS:
Thunderbird version is 45.5.1
Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS

THE PROBLEM:
My email server is hosted by a 3rd party, ie hosting company. On November 21st, 2016 they migrated my service onto a new server. Ever since Thunderbird on my Ubuntu system is unable to pull messages using IMAP on only one specific account(*), while it can do all other functions on the same account and has no issue on other accounts (I pull for now 3 mailboxes using this client).

(*)I can pull messages on any other system I use (I use mainly OS X based machines, as well some iOS and Android devices and have tested on a Wintel box and all can rx and tx this account).

HOW I PULL MESSAGES:
- Using IMAP protocol with secure SSL/TLS Settings IMAP 993 port and SMTP 465 (sending works like a charm, no issue, but pulling messages is stuck on November 21, 2016)

TROUBLESHOOTING STEPS TAKEN SO FAR:

- Checked all settings dozens of times to ensure I have it same as I have it for other accounts on the same email server, as well viewing settings like threads and folders, tried using unified inbox...NAH NO LOVE

- UnInstalled Thunderbird using Ubuntu's Ubuntu Software app - NO LOVE

- Removed the thunderbird.ini profile and related files in various combinations - NO LOVE (in my case its homed at /home/user/.thunderbird ) - this is also posting my me where I was looking for tips to ensure I am removing legit folders and files that remained [Complete Removal of Thunderbird 45.5.1 from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867574/complete-removal-of-thunderbird-45-5-1-from-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

- Completely removed Thunderbird from the system, including manual removal of cached files and folders, ie system was thunderbird free like it never had it before. Did re-install using Ubuntu Software and - NO LOVE

ERRORS FOUND (not checked systems logs yet)
Found the following error within "Error Console" related to Thunderbird, but am not sure how to address it and is that the source:

Timestamp: 03.01.2017 18:00:17
Error: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIMsgFolder.getStringProperty]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://messenger/content/folderPane.js :: getSmartFolderName :: line 2780"  data: no]
Source File: chrome://messenger/content/folderPane.js
Line: 2782

Also noticed within the profiles directory lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 15 Jan  3 19:50 lock -> 127.0.1.1:+4627 where the numbered linked locked directory changes every time I open new Thunderbird session.

Any comment that will lead me to some solution or at least to continue "better digging", is highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Lets be super sure the saved Thunderbird stuff is removed. Make sure Thunderbird is shut down, log out.  From another user account, log in. You can then either become root "sudo -s" iand cd into problem user account's home folder, or  just "sudo problem_user_name" and then "cd". That should put you in problem user's home.  Run "mv .thunderbird dot-thunderbird".  to be sure you truly have this cleaned out.  Log out, then log in and try thunderbird setup.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it turned out to be a malformed e-mail in the account.  Basically, I ended up deleting all of the mail in the account, and it started working properly afterwards.