# Thunderbird remove and purge not working

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird, software-uninstall

I'm having an issue where Thunderbird completely freezes on startup and suspect it comes from some of the account configurations.

I've been trying to completely reinstall it to try with a fresh config but every new installation still contains the same accounts, folders and even position on the quick access bar.

Based on this:
[How to completely remove Thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250996/how-to-completely-remove-thunderbird)

and this:
[Weird Thunderbird Uninstall Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295126/weird-thunderbird-uninstall-problem)

I've tried

`sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*`

Running `locate -e thunderbird` after a `sudo updatedb` returns a long list of dot files in my home directory and I don't get the impression that it has really been removed.

A fresh installation of the package with `sudo apt install thunderbird` just sets it all up exactly like before.

Very sorry if this is major noobage around installing or removing packages but I'm a bit clueless as to how to proceed...

Comment: Sow hat are those .dot files ? Just a few directories with content. Please update your question with al list of those directories.

Comment: Rename the hidden .thunderbird folder in your home directory to something else (e.g. .thunderbird_old) and start Thunderbird: it will start up with factory default settings.

Comment: Purging a package does not remove data stored in your /home dir. That's YOUR data, and the package manager won't remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These comments answered my questions. Thanks for the help guys.

> Rename the hidden .thunderbird folder in your home directory to something else (e.g. .thunderbird_old) and start Thunderbird: it will start up with factory default settings. – vanadium 2 days ago

> Purging a package does not remove data stored in your /home dir. That's YOUR data, and the package manager won't remove it. – user535733 2 days ago